# How to find the general term for Pell's sequence with Euler's method

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, pell-type-equations

Hello i try to find the general term for the Pell's sequence with this method called Euler's method .
$$
 a_{n+1}=2a_{n}+a_{n-1}
$$

What I tried here is :
$$G(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }a_{n}x^{n}$$
And i tried to expand the series of $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }a_{n+1}x^{n+1}$$
Like this:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }a_{n+1}x^{n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }(2a_{n}+a_{n-1})x^{n+1}=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }a_{n}x^{n+1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }a_{n-1}x^{n+1}=2x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }a_{n}x^{n}+x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }a_{n-1}x^{n}$$
But i don't know how to continue the method . I obtain there G(x) but i don't know what to do with the second series that contain a(n-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply by $x^n$, then sum from $n=1$ to $\infty$ to obtain
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n+1}x^n = 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1}x^n
$$
Then we have
$$
\frac1x(G(x) - a_0 -a_1x) = 2(G(x)-a_0)+xG(x)
$$
and hence
$$
G(x) = \frac{a_0+(a_1-2a_0)x}{1-2x-x^2}.
$$

Comment: Thank you a lot! And from now i can perform partial fraction decomposition and i will find the general term for Pell's sequence.